Structure relaxation: How can I be sure if my structure has realxed or not?
Im performing structural relaxation in VASP for tetragonal and orthorhombic systems with large lattice parameters. My INCAR settings contains the following:
EDIFF = 1E-8
EDDIFG = -0.001

The OUTCAR file shows:
Pulay Stress = 0.00 kB
External Pressure = +/- 0.04 kB
Total-Forces (eV/A) = 0.000123

Question:
Can I be confident my structures have truly relaxed based on these observations? How to ensure proper force convergence for large unit cells? Any other considerations for reliable relaxation?
Additional Information:
I'm concerned about the reliability of force convergence due to the inherently smaller forces in large unit cells.
I'm unsure if the strict energy convergence (EDIFF) is necessary for this case.

A robust but rather expensive way to check your structure is to calculate force-constants and look at vibrational frequencies. I use e.g. phonopy for this. Negative phonon frequencies (they are actually imaginary, but codes represent them as negative frequency) signal an instability. The instability could either be poor relaxation or a sign that your structure is only metastable (or is unstable).
